# Can fgets ever read an empty string?

Tags: c

Assuming the FILE* is valid, consider:

```
char buf[128];

if(fgets(buf,sizeof buf,myFile) != NULL) {
   strlen(buf) == 0; //can this ever be true ? In what cases ?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  Besides passing 1 (as noted by Ignacio), `fgets` doesn't do any special handling for embedded nulls.  So if the next character in the `FILE *` is NUL, `strlen` will be 0.  This is one of the reasons why I prefer the POSIX [getline](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) function.  It returns the number of characters read so embedded nulls are not a problem.

Answer (score 4):

From the `fgets(3)` man page:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>   fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
>   stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>   EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
>   A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.
> ```
>
> ...
>
> RETURN VALUE
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   gets() and fgets() return s on success, and NULL on error or  when end
>   of file occurs while no characters have been read.
> ```

From that, it can be inferred that a `size` of `1` will cause it to read an empty string. Experimentation here confirms that.

Incidentally, a `size` of `0` appears to not modify the buffer at all, not even putting in a `\0`.

Comment: if the buffer size is zero, there's nowhere for `fgets()` to write the terminal null, is there?  It can't write beyond the end of the space it is given; if it is given no space, it cannot write.